# How do I find a number in between numbers and colons?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I'm trying to get the numbers that's in between two colons and other numbers in a file.

Example:

```
1234:12345678:1234
1234:12345678:1234
1234:12345678:1234
```

I want the output to show all of the **12345678's** and nothing else.

Like this:

```
12345678
12345678
12345678
```

I achieved this using:

```
egrep -o "[0-9]{8}" file
```

Problem is that I need a different solution than egrep -o (awk or sed?)

I searched and tried a couple of things but without succes.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Use `sed 's/:\(.*\):/\1/' file` - to print between the de-limiters `:`, Using `Awk` may be tricky here if there are more than 3 columns and if you are not sure if the value will always be the 2nd column. This will work if there are more than 3 columns with different de-limiters present also

Comment: @Inian What this does is remove the colons and show all the numbers. I want to only see the 8 numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the "number" is always 2nd column, you could do with awk:

```
awk -F: '{print $2}' file
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! What if it's not always the 2nd column but there also is one in the 3rd? So I would want to see the 8 numbers of line 1, 2 and 3. line one = 12345678:1234:1234, line two = 1234:12345678:1234 and line three = 1234:1234:12345678. Not necessary but I'd like to know this too! :)

Comment: If the column you are interested in is 3rd, just change $2 to $3. If the length of column 2 must be 8 then you can do: `awk -F: '$2 && length($2)==8{print $2}' file`.

Comment: This is something interesting, thank you. Any idea how to show all 8 number long strings? No matter what column it is in.

Comment: You can use a loop: `awk -F: '{for (i=1;i<=NF; i++) if (length($i) == 8) print $i;}' file`.

Answer (score 0):

For the `awk` solution,

```
awk -F: '{print $2}' file
```

Or simply use `cut` to do that,

```
cut -d: -f2 file
```

Comment: Thanks! Both of the solutions work. Say I also want the 8 numbers of this example: 1234:1234:12345678 the command would not work if I also want that to show. So do you have any idea how I can make it show that too?

Comment: awk -F: '{print $3}' file

Comment: Yes this works if I want to see the 3rd column numbers. I wasn't clear about what I meant though. Say I want to see all of the 8 numbered columns. So 1234:1234:12345678 but also the 1234:12345678:1234. Thank you though!

Comment: Not tried this one, but I think you can use, `awk -F: '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i ~ /[0-9]{8}/)print $i}' file`

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything. Just like I also tried but it just wouldn't work, the [0-9]{8} does seem promising.

Comment: Mmm, not sure what I'm doing wrong then but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: It just puts me back to typing in the prompt. The command that @usr posted almost looks the same, the only difference is the range?

Comment: I use regex to do the filter, and @usr use length. Both methods should work. Can you give the exactly command you use?

Comment: I just copy pasted the command, and yes the file name is file :D. I was reading the man page of awk and I don't see why yours isn't working for me.

Comment: Never mind, just want to show the screencast in the last, https://imgur.com/a/ZW8g1 .

Comment: Let's see what's the output of `awk -F: '{print $1}' file`, and probably use `-F':'` as a substitution should help

Answer (score 0):

would this work?

```
awk -F':' '{print $2}' test > test results.txt
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're trying to make a file with the results in it. This doesn't work for me and does not seem it is what I'm trying to achieve :). Ty!